# Google Sheets/Microsoft Excel Numeric Row - Sort By Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a row that contains the following numbers:

```
26  29  37  28  25  41  46  42  39  37  30  25  51  49  57  53  33  28  45  50
```

I used the following function to sort this:

```
=SORT(A6:V6)
```

But it did'nt sort it...
Can someone give me a direction on how i can do this?
Any docs from Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel that explains this, or if it's not too much trouble and you want to help me right away, i will be appreciated it.

I tried on both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel, neither of them sorted right.

Output of the function:

```
26  29  37  28  25  41  46  42  39  37  30  25  51  49  57  53  33  28  45  50
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need the forth criterion to sort by column: `=SORT(A6:V6,,,TRUE)` in excel.  please see the documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c  I do not see that ability in Google sheets.

Comment: I did that right now and it is returning N/A ...

Comment: It will only work in excel. Not Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel:

```
=SORT(A1:T1,1,1,TRUE)
```

[image]

In sheets:

```
=transpose(sort(transpose(A1:T1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! This did it...